# How can I write this relatively simple criteria query involving three domains?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

Just for background, let us have these three domain classes:

```
class Group {
    Long id
    Person person
}

class Person {
    Long id
    Country country
    String name
}

class Country {
    Long id
}
```

So, with these classes in mind, I am given a Group object's id as well as a Country object's id. I would like to get the list of Person objects based on these two.

It seems relatively simple, but I am new to criteria queries and so I am struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong. This is what I have so far:

```
def c = Group.createCriteria()
def names = c.list (order: "asc") {
    createAlias('person', 'p')
    createAlias('p.country', 'c')
    and {
        eq ('c.id', Long.valueOf(countryId))
        eq ('id', groupId)
    }
    projections {
        property('p.name')
    }
}
```

Of course, this is wrong as it is throwing errors. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Throwing errors? What errors?

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: Well, this is just an example mock up that I used to demonstrate my problem. However, I get the error invalid identifier for the country id.

Answer (score 0):

```
static def searchPersons(Map params) {
    return Group.createCriteria().list(params, {
        if(params.groupId) {
            eq('id', params.groupId.toLong())
        }
        person {
            order('name')
            if(params.countryId) {
                country {
                    eq('id', params.countryId.toLong())
                }
            }
        }
        projections {
            property('person')
        }

    })
}
```

Still, it might be better to add the necessary associations (*hasMany*, etc.) on your domains.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is improve the associations between your domain classes. This will help make criteria queries simpler (and deter monkey-patching later).

In your example, the association between `Person` an `Group` is a *one-to-many*; one person can have many groups. That may be your intention, but it also means that a group can have only one person. Basically, there's no way to group people together.

I'm going to assume that you want a many-to-one relationship so that many `Person` (people) can be in the same `Group`. With this in mind, the domain classes (with the explicit IDs left in) would look like this:

```
class Group {
    Long id
}

class Person {
    Long id
    Country country
    String name
    Group group
}

class Country {
    Long id
}
```

As for the query, since your expected result is instances of `Person`, the best place to start is with `Person` rather than `Group`.

## List of Person instances

Here's how to get a list of `Person` instances.

### Where query

```
def people = Person.where {
    country.id == countryId
    group.id == groupId
}.list()
```

### Criteria query

```
def people = Person.withCriteria {
    country {
        eq 'id', countryId as Long
    }

    group {
        eq 'id', groupId
    }
}
```

## List of Person names

Notice that there's a discrepancy between your question and example. You asked for a list of `Person` instances, yet your example demonstrates attempting to get a list of `Person` *names* .

Here's how to get a list of names of the `Person` instances.

### Where query

```
def names = Person.where {
    country.id == countryId
    group.id == groupId
}.projections {
    property 'name'
}.list()
```

### Criteria query

```
def names = Person.withCriteria {
    country {
        eq 'id', countryId as Long
    }

    group {
        eq 'id', groupId
    }

    projections {
        property 'name'
    }
}
```